# I am using Python on Windows. How do I delete my script after it is run?

Tags: python, windows, scripting

I have written a Python script and compiled it into a MS Windows EXE file. I can modify the code, but how do I make it remove itself after running?

Comment: Why do you want it to be deleted after it runs?

Comment: Delete the script or the EXE?

Comment: Application deletes itself and finishes execution? Doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Hmmm, a script that you want to run and then leave no trace of itself? I hope you intend to use this power for the Forces of Good.

Comment: Yes, it is an installer for an educational software program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is make an external .bat file that executes your exe file and deletes it when finished.